# incompatible type error ?i can not understand what i am doing wrong?

Tags: ios, xcode

```
NSString *docsDir; 
NSArray *dirPaths; 
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
// Build the path to the database file
docsDir   = dirPaths[0];/// at this point i receive an error that incompatible type error plxxxx help me
```

Comment: Is there any more details about the error?

Comment: Sir i am new in ios development..I have no more details about this error

Comment: I test your code with my xcode 6,it works well.So please show more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *docsDir; 
NSArray *dirPaths; 
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
// Build the path to the database file

docsDir=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dirPaths[0]];
```

Comment: You can't have two variable with the same name in the same scope.

Comment: And why do you think you need to use `stringWithFormat:`?

Comment: No since you still have a needless use of `stringWithFormat`. `dirPaths[0]` is already an `NSString`.

Comment: why r u questioning on other person answer why u r not upload ur own answer ?

Comment: this is my(sanjeet) code not mady code @Muhammad Ali

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below code

```
  NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

  NSString *sql_Path=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

It will help you.

Comment: How is this different from the code in the question? It's the same other than your answer uses the old array syntax and the question uses the new array syntax.

Comment: We can give the solution either this way or that one.Here if he puts[paths objectAtIndex:0] in his code,It will work.This is the used to reduce the code that's why i set in just 2 lines.

Comment: But your code is effectively the same as the code in the question. Your answer doesn't explain why the code in the question isn't working.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct.it is not a problem may be.The coding of another part is something wrong infact.